# Unexpected output in VERY basic C++ program

Tags: c++

EDIT: My last question is how do I get a space before the number I put and then put a . at the end of the sentence?

**Original Question:**

I am learning C++.  This is my code

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int iNum;
    std::cout << "Please enter your favorite number" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> iNum;
    std::cout << "Your favorite number is" << std::cout << iNum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I removed the spaces to make it easier to read.  I expect the output to be Your favorite number is 4 if I were to enter a 4 when asked.  Instead it says, Your favorite number is51ABC3E84.  The last number will always be whatever number I pick.  What am I messing up to get the weird output?  Thanks for the help for a very noob programmer.

Comment: Why is the `std::cout` in there (it's convertible to a `void *` in 03, even if most C++11 compilers now don't have that changed yet)?

Comment: Try this `std::cout << "Your favorite number is" << iNum << std::endl;`

Comment: Now try this `std::cout << "Your favorite number is " << iNum << "." << std::endl;`

Comment: BTW I posted comments only because I am not actually explaining anything, just giving you a solution. I hope you can figure out what is going on from the solution, but in my mind this doesn't constitute a good answer.

Comment: Hey I figured as much juanchopanza.  I picked an answer down below that explained what you said. Thanks still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the second `std::cout` after you retrieved input, that serves no purpose in your program.

The corrected line should be: (updated to reflect updated parts of question)

`std::cout << "Your favorite number is " << iNum << "." << std::endl;`

When you send `std::cout` into the stream, you're actually having the `std::cout` object try to process itself as something to be printed.  In this case, it seems to be interpreting it as a 32-bit value (probably the memory location of `std::cout`) represented in hex.  The "4" at the end of "51ABC3E8" in your output is the value of the variable taken from input.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why what juanchopanza said actually solved the problem.  This is a huge help.  I'm glad that there is such a helpful community here to learn from, and with such quick answers no less.

Answer (score 3):

```
 std::cout << "Your favorite number is" << std::cout << iNum << std::endl;
                                        //^^You are printing cout
```

should be

```
std::cout << "Your favorite number is"  << iNum << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to say `std::cout` once. After the initial `cout`, you just chain all the output you want with `<<` until the statement ends in a `;`. When you put it behind `<<` as in your code, you're actually printing `cout` as converted to a `void*`.

`std::cout << "Your favorite number is" << iNum << std::endl;` ought to do the trick for you.

EDIT: If you want a space and period, just put them in your output line:

```
std::cout << "Your favorite number is " << iNum << '.' << std::endl;
```